# Validation message for FormRequest in Laravel

Tags: validation, laravel-5.6

I have a FormRequest class like below

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreImageRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'uploadImage' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,|max:2048',
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I get validation message here ? Like if the file is not an `Image` or the file size is not within `max:2048`.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

override the `messages()` method in the `StoreImageRequest.php`.

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
            'uploadImage.mimes' => 'Custom error message.',
    ];
}
```

laravel doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#customizing-the-error-messages)

Comment: Thanks @ab_in. But it is not working. I am getting output like below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEHDm.png

Comment: add this in your controller. `use App\Http\Requests\StoreImageRequest;`